# How to get a field from another collection and replace with null if not found?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have following shcemas:

```js
employeeSchema: {
     _id: ObjectId
     isActive: Boolean
}
```

```js
careerSchema: {
    employeeId: ObjectId // points to the _id from employeeSchema
    isCurrentlyWorking: Boolean
    position: String // designation
}
```

I want to find the employees that have field `isActive: true`. Also, the same employee may have more than one document in the Career collection. I want to find the document with `isCurrentlyWorking: true` and want that document's `position` field to be in the employee document's `career` field. I have tried the following:

```js
const result = await Employee.aggregate([
    { $match: { isActive: true } },
    {
         from: "careers",
         localField: "_id",
         foreignField: "employeeId",
         as: "career",
         pipeline: [
             { $match: { isCurrentlyWorking: true} },
             { $project: { position: 1} }
         ]
    }
])
```

The problem that I have faced with this is the field `career` is an empty array in the `result`. And because of that I cannot add `{ $unwind: "$career" }` to the aggregate function. One more thing, some employees may not have any correspoding document in the `Careers` collection. In that case, I just want the `result` to have `career: null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to do something like:

```
db.employees.aggregate([
  {$match: {isActive: true}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "careers",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "employeeId",
      as: "career",
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {isCurrentlyWorking: true}},
        {$project: {position: 1}}
      ]
  }},
  {$unwind: {
      path: "$career",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
  }},
  {$set: {career: {$ifNull: ["$career", null]}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AzG2BSjuHcC)